# Spring PropertyPlaceHolder Issue

Tags: java, spring

I am working with Spring 4.1.5.RELEASE. In the context file loads instead of resolving placeholders from entry in the property files, it just inserts the placeholder entry into the bean directly.

Context file

```
<context:property-placeholder 
    location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties,classpath*:conf/*.properties" 
    ignore-resource-not-found="true"/>
 <jaxws:client id="imiClient"
              serviceClass="com.imi.ws.mail.MailPortType"
              address="${imi.ws.fulfillment.service}">
    <jaxws:inInterceptors>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" />
    </jaxws:inInterceptors>
    <jaxws:outInterceptors>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" />
    </jaxws:outInterceptors>
</jaxws:client>
<http:conduit name="*.http-conduit">
    <http:tlsClientParameters disableCNCheck="true"/>
</http:conduit>
```

Property File

```
imi.ws.fulfillment.service=http://localhost:8076/Mail/MailWebService
```

Anytime i invoke a web method on the created bean, i get the exception below

```
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 1: ${imi.ws.fulfillment.service}
at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3105)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3063)
at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.setupURI(HTTPConduit.java:664)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.prepare(HTTPConduit.java:458)
... 45 more
```

THe placeholder ${imi.ws.fulfillment.service} was not resolved. I tried debugging the application and realized the property file was indeed loader and all other entries were available.

I used **@Value** annotation and i got the expected result.
Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Other bean declaration with placeholder has their values injected. I was able to verify this by debugging the application. Only the ***imiClient*** bean instance was not injected.

```
<bean id="encryptorDecryptor" class="com.mail.util.EncryptorDecryptor" factory-method="getInstance">
    <constructor-arg index="0" type="String" value="${encryption.cert.location}"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" type="String" value="${encryption.cert.duration}"/>
    <constructor-arg index="2" type="String" value="${props}"/>
</bean>
```

Property file

```
encryption.cert.location=${file.basedir}\\EncryptionCert\\enc.cert
encryption.cert.duration=10
props=META-INF/spring/mail.properties
```

Comment: It won't work. When properties are used in namespace there must be explicit support in the namespace for it, if there isn't it will not work. As a workaround you could not use the namespace and configure everything from the jax-ws client manually.

Comment: This has always worked until yeaterday, but then can you expantiate more on the name space thing you talked about and also the work around you proposed.

Comment: Well no as that is pretty much it. If a namespace doesn't support placeholders there isn't much you can do. The placeholders must be replaced by the `BeanDefinitionParser`s that are behind the namespace parsing, if not, nothing is going to happen. The workaround is as is, ditch the usage of the namespace, figure out what it does and configure all the beans manually..

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum, i was able to solve by the problem by doing a classpath cleaning. I removed all unused jars and all seems to work fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem. Apparently I had a couple of spring jars on my classpath which the application was not using, So I cleaned them up and the proper value was injected instead of the placeholder.